# Different activation function in same layer of a Neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, activation-function, mathematics

My question is that what will happen if I arrange different activation functions in the same layer of a neural network and continue the same trend for the other hidden layers.

Suppose I have 3 `relu` units in the starting and 3 `tanh` after that and other activation function I the same hidden layer and for the other hidden layers I am scaling all the nodes with the same scale (decreasing/increasing) and the arrangement and order of the activation function is not changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At a higher level, using multiple activation functions in a NN may not work as these activation functions operate differently for the same inputs. For an input of -1.56, ReLU will a 0, sigmoid will give a 0.174 and Tanh will give -0.91. These differences will not allow the gradients to flow uniformly during backpropagation.

You may try using two different activation functions in the same layers. I can think of some issues which may arise,

- Talking about the combination of Tanh and ReLU functions, we can face the problem of *exploding gradients*. ReLU functions provide the same inputs as outputs if they're zero or positive. On the other hand, Tanh function provides outputs in the range [ -1, 1 ]. Large positive values will pass through the ReLU function unchanged but while passing through the Tanh function, you'll always get a fully saturated firing i.e an output of 1 always.
- Therefore, while using ReLU in a classification problem, we use softmax instead of the sigmoid function. If the sigmoid function is used, you'll probably get an output of ones only.

Instead of the ReLU-Tanh combination, you may want to use the Sigmoid-Tanh combination.

- Here, the sigmoid may give an output of 0 ( or a number close to zero ), if given a negative value. These negative values may be supplied by the Tanh function in the preceding layers. You may face overfitting here.

Comment: Thanks, i was thinking about some similar activation function but then they won't even have too much difference from a network with all same activation functions, this thing came to my mind from the inception network which does all kind of convolutions and stacks them.